# The use of the past perfect after the present perfect in one sentence

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect, past-simple

Could you tell if it's correct to use the past simple or the past perfect in the following sentence.

> I haven't mended the jeans that I **tore**.
>
> I haven't mended the jeans that I **had torn**.

If both are perfectly correct, then what is the difference? If there is no difference in meaning, then which one is more common?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use present perfect: I haven't mended the jeans that I have torn, because the jeans were torn in the past, but have a tear in them now. "I haven't mended" expresses a present situation, my jeans are still torn.

You could also say: I haven't mended the jeans that I tore last week, a few days ago, the other day,etc. If you mention when the jeans were torn, past simple is appropriate.

Past perfect is used to indicate that something happened before another event in the past. So "I hadn't mended the jeans that I had torn" is better. You hadn't mended the jeans in the past, that had been torn at a moment even further in the past.

Comment: What about if said "I have never mended the clothes I had torn", woud the past perfect be appropriate here?

Comment: I don't think that makes a difference, I would still use present perfect: the clothes I have torn.